# what does 'elem' means in 'for elem in smiles'?

Tags: python, for-loop

Can somebody please tell me that what `elem` means in `for elem in smiles`? I am learning programming by all my own and I have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have an object that contains other objects, probably an Array.
In your example, this is called `smiles`.

`for elem in smiles` will loop over each item in this array and assign the value of the current item to `elem`.

So imagine smiles is build up like this: `[1,2,3]`, then the loop will run 3 times. Elem will be `1` the first run, `2` on the second and `3` on the third run.